# getClassLoader().getResource() throwing NullPointerException? Why not FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, file, io, nullpointerexception

I am trying to load files in a program I am working on. I am doing this through the use of getClassLoader().getResource(). This works perfectly when the file is able to be found. However, when the file cannot be found it throws a NullPointerException. Shouldn't it be throwing a FileNotFoundException instead, or does getResource() just not throw such an exception?

Here's the code (pretty standard file loading):

```
public static File loadFile(String path) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    return new File(FileHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path).getFile());
}

//somewhere else
loadFile("data/xt.txt");
```

if xt.txt exists, the code works fine. If not, it throws a NullPointerException. I can easily modify my code to handle the NullPointerException, but I just can't think of why it's returning null in the first place instead of FileNotFound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getResource` *doesn't* throw an exception. It returns `null` if the resource is not found.

*Your code* throws the exception when it tries to call `getFile` on the null reference returned by `getResource`.

You could do this:

```
URL resourceURL = FileHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path);
if(resourceURL == null)
    throw new FileNotFoundException(path+" not found");
return new File(resourceURL.getFile());
```

Comment: Actually, no, he can't do that.  `getFile()` *does not* convert a file: URL to a file path, despite the method name.  It just returns the path portion of a URL (everything after the scheme and host, if any).  If the URL happens to represent, for instance, a filename with a space in it, getFile() will return a string containing `%20` rather than the actual space.  So passing that string to a File constructor is not reliable.

Comment: @VGR The question, as asked, is about the NullPointerException, not about getFile.

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you saying I __shouldn't__ do this?

Comment: @TheNewGuy think about it - what will your code do if the resource is found inside a JAR file, or on a HTTP server? (You might not have put your code inside a JAR file or on a HTTP server, but someone might)

Comment: I've used this method of obtaining files in previous programs and it worked fine after being converted to a JAR. I had to switch over to this method at one point because it was the only way I could find to obtain files inside of the program after it's been converted to a .jar.

Comment: @TheNewGuy there is no way to get a `File` object referring to an entry in a JAR, because entries in JARs aren't files.

Comment: @immibis I understand what you're saying. I decided it would be a better route to switch to using external folders as resources instead. My original plan was to have all the files inside of the program, which would be a jar file, in which case this method would work fine. However, since I will be adding/removing files often and will need to change/edit them external folders are the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

This code throws a NullPointerException because:

1. `FileHandler.class.getClassLoader().getResource(path)` returns `null` if resource is not found — it's defined this way in Java specs.
2. Invoking `.getFile()` on `null` is a NullPointerException .

That said, please note that:

- A resource is *not necessarily a file*, so `FileNotFoundException` is not appropriate for resources in general.
- Constructor of `File` class does *not* throw an exception if the file does not exist. You may use `File.exists()` to check if the file really exists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have had this issue. This is how I fix it but I hate how I have to do it.

Here is the situation and fix:
I am running code on a Mac. I have a res folder with my database structure inside.
The getResource command looks like:

```
ArchiverSQL a = new ArchiverSQL();
File file = new File(a.getClass().getResource("/database/structure/settings.sql").getFile()); 
   try (FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader)) {

       String line;
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
           System.out.println(line);
       }
   }
```

Then when this code is run I get a FileNotFound Error.
/Volumes/MainFiles%201/Code/IdeaProjects/theProgram/target/classes/database/structure/settings.sql
The MainFiles%201 should read as "MainFiles 1" and for some reason it won't find the file if I use the %201 that is generated by the getResource() function.

This is what I have to do which makes me irritated.

```
File file = new File(a.getClass().getResource("/database/structure/settings.sql")
.getFile().replaceAll("%20","\\ "));
```

I have to adjust the string returned with a "\ " which will become "\ " and then it all magically works again. I have a feeling I will now have to write the flip side of this for Windows since my software works on both platforms.

I hope this helps anyone else having this issue, please let me know if you have a better solution.